# In MVC, how to add intellisense to the html helpers

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I am wondering if there is a way to allow the intellisense to work with the html attributes of the mvc helpers like

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.FieldName, new {@class="from-control col-md-3"})
```

Is there a way to allow intellisense inside ( @class= "... here ..." )?

Comment: The HtmlAttributes in this syntax is just an `object` class. There's no way for Intellisense to work.

Comment: No.. and that's why the .Net developers got upset that nobody could use all of the intellisense they added to visual studio 2013 and changed everything over to Tag helpers in 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is intellisense will not work since the `@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.FieldName, new {@class="from-control col-md-3"})` is a C# code, so css intellisense  will not work inside c#.

Answer (score 0):

Had you tried using the "web essentials" extension within Visual Studio?

Comment: already i am using it with visual studio 2015 and no option in it to support this case.